# Trouble training VGG16 on CIFAR100 dataset [Keras]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, vgg-net

I am trying to train `VGGNET-16` from `Keras` library on `CIFAR-100` dataset but validation accuracy and loss are not improving, I think I am doing some mistake while pre-processing the data.

I have tried CIFAR-100 dataset from Keras library but still facing same issue.

**Code**

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import to_categorical

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import os


train_path = r'/content/cifar-100/train'
test_path  = r'/content/cifar-100/test'

classes = ['class1', 'class2', ...,  'class100']


def load_train():

    images    = []
    labels    = []

    for fields in classes:

        index = classes.index(fields)
        path = os.path.join(train_path, fields, '*g')
        files = glob.glob(path)

        for fl in files:

          # Image
          image = cv.imread(fl)
          images.append(image)

          # Label
          label = np.zeros(len(classes))
          label[index] = 1.0
          labels.append(label)

    images = np.array(images)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    return images, labels

X_train, y_train = load_train()

model = VGG16(weights=None, classes=len(classes), input_shape=(32, 32, 3))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=40, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True)
```

**Output**

```
Epoch 1/40
45000/45000 [==============================] - 16s 357us/sample - loss: 4.5153 - acc: 0.0157 - val_loss: 7.7937 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
...
Epoch 10/40
45000/45000 [==============================] - 11s 248us/sample - loss: 3.2936 - acc: 0.1981 - val_loss: 10.8545 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
...
Epoch 20/40
45000/45000 [==============================] - 11s 248us/sample - loss: 2.3035 - acc: 0.3951 - val_loss: 13.5597 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
...
Epoch 30/40
45000/45000 [==============================] - 11s 248us/sample - loss: 0.7384 - acc: 0.7818 - val_loss: 21.9027 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
...
Epoch 40/40
45000/45000 [==============================] - 11s 248us/sample - loss: 0.1570 - acc: 0.9527 - val_loss: 30.7987 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

**Data directory**

[image]

Can anyone please have a look at the code.

Comment: Sounds like huge overfitting, maybe huge class imbalance, or badly designed models such as having `BatchNormalization` after `Dropout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try multiple things given your labels and images are correct.

1) You can try normalizing the image before giving t to the model.

```
    image = image / 255.
```

or you can also use min-max normalization

```
min_val = np.min(image)
max_val = np.max(image)
image = (image-min_val) / (max_val-min_val)
```

2) You can use pre-trained weights from imagenet by :

```
model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", classes=len(classes), input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
```

3) You can use a custom optimizer and tweak the learning rate .

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.adam(lr=2e-5)
```

4) As suggested by Daniel you can add dropout and batch normalization layers to reduce over fitting.